# how to send extra arguments to another function

Tags: python

I wants to send extra arguments to another function, is this the right way to do that.

```
def foo(self, request, method='post', page=None,**options):
    #do something
    self.another_foo(options)

def another_foo(self, data=None):
    print data

self.foo(5,data="free")
```

Comment: That depends on what that other function expects to receive.

Comment: Please add more details on the aim of the function and what you want to achieve. Also do they need to be named arguments?

Comment: updated the question, I want to use data in another_foo.

Comment: Why don't you try it, and see? As written, `data` in `another_foo` will be *the dictionary* (`{'data': 'free'}`). If instead you want `data` in `another_foo` to be `'free'`, then you need to use `self.another_foo(**options)` - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: Do you want the extra arguments to appear in the function as a tuple (positional) or as a dictionary (keyword arguments)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass it using [**-notation](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another), the same way as you receive it:

```
def foo(self, request, method='post', page=None, **options):
    #do something
    self.another_foo(**options)
```